Boot failure of Ubuntu v24.04 after upgrade on Raspberry Pi 4B?
I recently had Ubuntu on my Raspberry Pi4B say that updates would no longer be available for my particular version, and then it asked me if I wanted to upgrade to the latest version (v24.04).  I decided to allow the upgrade, but when it completed, I could no longer boot my Raspberry Pi4.  I get errors saying that cups.service failed and nmbd.service failed.
How can I repair this issue?  I had Pi-hole and my block lists on it and also I want my other files back, but a fresh install of Ubuntu on a different card won't allow me to read the previous card.  I can only read it using Linux Mint on my PC.
